# What is the distribution of characteristic function $g(t)=\frac{1+t^2}{1+a^2t^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

How to find a distribution of the following characteristic function
\begin{align}
g(t)=\frac{1+t^2}{1+a^2t^2},
\end{align}
for $a>1$.

Since,
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty}g(t)=\frac{1}{a^2}.
\end{align}
This means that the distribution is neither continuos nor discrete.

I was also able to show that 
\begin{align}
F(0)-F(0^{-})=\frac{1}{a^2}
\end{align}
which means that there is a mass at zero.

However, I am not able to show anything more about distribution $F$.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1+t^2}{1+a^2 t^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} 1 + (1-\frac{1}{a^2}) \frac{1}{1+a^2 t^2}.$$

That is, we are looking at the convex combination of ${\bf 1}$ and \frac{1}{1+a^2 t^2}$.

Now $1$ is the characteristic function of the random variable equal to $0$ with probability $1$.

Let $X\sim \mbox{Exp}(1/a)$ and let $Y$ be independent of $X$ equal to  $1$ or $-1$ with probability  $\frac12$ each. The characteristic function of $Z=XY$ is  (I'm skipping the calculation):

$$\frac{1}{1+a^2 t^2}.$$

This is known as centered Laplace distribution. Simply ``symmetrized" exponential. Denote this distribution by $\mbox{Laplace}(a)$. Note that it is equal in distribution to  $a\times \mbox{Laplace}(1)$.

Back to our original equation.

Let $W\sim \mbox{Bern}(1-\frac{1}{a^2})$, independent of $Z$, it follows that the answer to our question is

$$(1-W) \times 0 + W Z=WZ \sim a\times \mbox{Bern}(1-\frac{1}{a^2})\times \mbox{Laplace}(1).$$